# Results are coming one over another in android PlaceAutocompleteFragment Search widget Provided by Google Places

Tags: android, search, autocomplete, google-places-api

I have used PlaceAutocompleteFragment provided by Google Places Api to integrate Autocomplete search in my Android Application.
It is working fine but the problem is sometime the results in autocomplete list is coming one over another.
I am not able to think about the issue. I am adding the screenshot and code for the same.

[Screenshot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Myo32.jpg)

code -

Layout code -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coord"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.restaurantfinder.lazylad91.restaurantfinder.HomeActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
                />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_home"/>

<!--    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"/>-->

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Activity code -

```
    AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder()
            .setTypeFilter(AutocompleteFilter.TYPE_FILTER_ESTABLISHMENT)
            .build();
    autocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);

    autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
            // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
            mPlaceSelected = place;

            }
            Log.d("TAG", "Place: " + place.getName());//get place details here
        }
```

**UPDATE**

This bug was handled by Google in issue

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35829225

The fix was implemented in Google Play Services 9.6 (21 Sep 2016)

Comment: Bug report filed: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=10292

Comment: This is now fixed in Google Play Services 9.6 for Jellybean and up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in the Autocomplete widget for Android. It will be fixed in an upcoming release.

Comment: do you have any idea when it will be fixed? Still issue is producible. Thanks

Comment: Expect the fix for this to roll out mid-September (give or take a week).